# Instantiating a c++ class in x86 (32bit) assembly (Passing a c++ class by copy to a method in assembly)

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, multiple-languages

In my project, I have, amongst many other things, to call a c++ method from assembly and to pass a class by copy. It would be quite simple if I could pass it by reference, but I cannot.

I assume it would look something like this:
create a new instance of said class;
copy the attributes of the class to the attributes of the new class;
push a pointer to the new class onto the stack;
call the method;
call the destructor of the class that's a copy of the other class.

So the real question is, how do you instantiate a class that was created in c++ in assembly?

Thank you all very much in advance.

Edit: I am working with gcc on a Fedora 14 powered x86 personal computer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating a class object isn't much different from creating a normal stack variable. You just need to call the (copy-)constructor.
You make space on the stack for the local class object, push the object to create the copy from on the stack (as the argument for the copy ctor), pass the address of the local space<sup>1)</sup> and finally call the copy constructor of the class you want to create.
Then just push that local object on the stack and call your function. Afterwards you pass the address of your local object again<sup>1)</sup> and call the destructor.
How to exactly code that depends on your platform/architecture.

<sup>1)</sup> The `ecx` register is used to pass the `this` pointer on MSVC. GCC passes `this` as a hidden first parameter. Differences are summed up [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Either_caller_or_callee_clean-up). Only know this for x86 architecture, not for others, sorry.

Comment: I believe this works with VC++. In GCC, I believe you have to push the pointer `this` on the stack as if it was a parameter instead of putting it in `%ecx`.

Answer (score 4):

Anything relating to assembly is dependent on the processor and platform you're writing for.

The safest way to do what you ask is to allocate space on the stack for a new object of the class, and generate a call to the class' copy constructor.

General answer: instantiating a C++ class involves generating a call to a constructor.

This doesn't seem like the most practical exercise… usually assembly is used within C++, not the other way around, via the `asm` keyword. In the rare exceptions, a plain C interface layer is used (via `extern "C"`), not the C++ application binary interface.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You made me notice I had not written what architecture I'm working with.
I am working with an x86 fedora 14 box with gcc.
As to the practicability of the exercice, I have no choice.
It is part of a sizable college project; the teachers seem to have forgotten to write about this part in the notes.

Comment: Is it 64-bit x86 or 32-bit x86? For any recent version of Linux it could be either and it makes a huge difference. As to the practicability, I'd ask your teacher about it - you may have misunderstood the project's requirements or overlooked an easier way.

Comment: just to note, 64bit x86 is named x86_64 or also amd64. I commonly see amd64 mentioned for intel processors, so I'm not sure if it's just confusion, or there really isn't a branding issue. but x86 by itself typically refers to 32bit machines.

Comment: @Tcll It's called AMD64 because it was designed by AMD and later adopted by Intel.